# Python skipping functions when ran in VS Code

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

I have written the following python code to read in XYZ data as CSV and then grid to a GTiff format.

When I run the code I am getting no errors.

However, after trying to debug, I added some print statements and noticed that the functions aren't actually being called.

How can I run this script so that it all completes?

```
import sys
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import rasterio
from datetime import datetime
from osgeo import gdal


class gdal_toolbox:

    ## CONSTANTS ##

    ## API handling Globals ##
    gdal_types = [  'GDT_Unknown','GDT_Byte','GDT_UInt16','GDT_Int16',\
                    'GDT_UInt32','GDT_Int32','GDT_Float32','GDT_Float64',\
                    'GDT_CInt16','GDT_CInt32','GDT_CFloat32','GDT_CFloat64',\
                    'GDT_TypeCount' ]
    jobDict = {}
    xyz_dict = {}
    layerJson = {}
    msk = {}

    def __init__( self, kwargs ):

        self.jobDict = kwargs

        if self.jobDict['no_data'] is None:
            self.jobDict['no_data'] = -11000
        else:
            self.jobDict['no_data'] = int(self.jobDict['no_data'])
        
        if self.jobDict['gridAlgorithm'] is None:
            self.jobDict['gridAlgorithm'] = 'nearest:radius1=2.25:radius2=2.25:nodata=' + str(self.jobDict['no_data'])


    def normalizeToCsv( self ):
            MAX_POINTS = 64000000

            try:
                
                # Read in ungridded data
                self.df = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/......xyz', sep='\s+|,|:|\t',header=None, engine='python')

                cnt = self.df.shape[0]
                if(cnt > MAX_POINTS):
                    raise ValueError('Maximum number of points (' + str(cnt) + ' > ' + str(MAX_POINTS) + ') in datasource exceeded')


                # convert to named x,y,z columns
                print(str(datetime.now()) + ' normalizeToCsv: to_csv (start)')
                self.ds = self.df.to_csv(self.csv_buf,sep=',',header=['x','y','z'],index=None)
                self.csv_buf.seek(0)
                print(str(datetime.now()) + ' normalizeToCsv: to_csv (end)')

                dfsize = sys.getsizeof(self.df)
                print('df (1) size : ' + str(dfsize))
                #return df
                
            except Exception as e:
                self.logException(e)
                raise 
            

    def csvToTiff(self):

            try:
                x = self.xyz_dict['xAxis'] / self.xyz_dict['xCellSize']
                y = self.xyz_dict['yAxis'] / self.xyz_dict['yCellSize']
        
                no_data = str(self.jobDict['no_data'])

                if self.jobDict['srs'] is not None:
                    srs = self.jobDict['srs']
                elif self.jobDict['wkt'] is not None:
                    srs = rasterio.crs.CRS.from_wkt(self.jobDict['wkt'])

                option = gdal.GridOptions(format = 'GTIFF', outputType = gdal.GDT_Float32,  width = x, height = y, \
                    outputBounds = [self.xyz_dict['minX'], self.xyz_dict['minY'], self.xyz_dict['maxX'], self.xyz_dict['maxY']], \
                    outputSRS = srs, algorithm=self.jobDict['gridAlgorithm'])
        
                self.ds_tif = gdal.Grid('C:/Users/Public/......tif', self.ds, options = option)
                
            except Exception as e:
                self.logException(e)
                raise
```

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = gdal_toolbox(kwargs)
    app.run()
```

or

```
 if __name__ == "__main__":
    gdal_toolbox(kwargs).run()
```

Use thease codes at the end of your script.

And the solution is :

```
class gdal_toolbox:

    ## CONSTANTS ##

    def __init__( self, kwargs ):
        print(kwargs)



    def normalizeToCsv( self ):
            MAX_POINTS = 64000000
            print(MAX_POINTS)

        

    def csvToTiff(self):

          print("Its the secoend function")
      
      
if __name__ == "__main__":
 
    kwargs="Its the keyword arguments"
    gdal_toolbox(kwargs)
```

Comment: I get the error that gdal_toolbox is not defined despite it being the class name

Comment: Solved ! You can check now ....

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are not executing anything in this piece of code, just defining class and functions within it, right?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure how to execute the class